# xpage saving document from one view to another

Tags: xpages

I have two views one view is in a dialog that opens by clicking a button and other view is in the same xpag I want to save data from view in dialog into view in the xpage

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getComponent("myDialog").hide()` can take a parameter of a panel / other component on the underlying XPage that you want to refresh.
The client-side equivalent, `XSP.closeDialog()`, takes a second parameter of the client-side ID of the panel / other component on the underlying XPages that you want to refresh.

That should allow you to pass values from the dialog to the XPage.